# How to select a random row in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, random

My table is like this:

```
id,url,name,imagelink
```

and I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM id WHERE id="randomid"
```

I want to get all the data from a random row like `id=17,url17,name17,imagelink17` and save it in variables afterwords. e.g $currentid,$currenturl,  $currentname, $currentimagelink

I've tried something like that:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20";
```

which obviously did not work. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: @kingkero Make that an answer ;)

Comment: @kingkero Wrong, he needs to use `IN`

Comment: that will return all of the entries. I just want to display one

Comment: lol forget it of course i have to set the limit to 1

Comment: @Mr.Alien no, @kingero's solution works fine. the only problem in the OPs curretn code is the syntax error in his `where` clause and the fact that the `where` clause is superfluous anyway.

Comment: @JohannesH. Oh, I thought he wanted to fetch rows by using multiple ids in the condition

Comment: @Sadikhasan there is a time limit before you can actually accept an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't want a specific row, leave the `WHERE id=` out of the query and it should work.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

will return 20 random rows,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

will give you only one

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept the answer in 10min ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

and for the variables you can have

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {

        $currenid=$row['id'];
        $currenturl=$row['url']; 
        $currentname=$row['name'];
        $currentimagelink=$row['imagelink'];

      }
```

Comment: @kingkero made the query perfectly, but i also posted this because he didnt write how to set the variables, hope i helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You can have query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Isn't this (basically) the same as kingkero's answer?

Comment: when i posted, this answer, there was not showing. may be net slow problem

Comment: No worries, @Shri. You can delete your answer, if you want to. Personally, I think there's no need for two exact same answers to exist on the same thread. :-)